# How can I make my nav bar span the width of the entire div

Tags: html, css, web

EDIT: I did manage to figure it out in flex! But the links still aren't quite taking up the entire top row:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/frPfm.jpg)

there's still some extra space to the right and left. Is there any way to force the flex to use all the available space?

I'd like the nav bar to automatically adjust width based on how many links there are.

```css
.top-container {
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
}

.top-content-box {
  width: 90%;
  height: 30%;
  margin: 30px auto;
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #000;
  justify-content: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.news-and-twitter {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.twitter-min {
  width: 300px;
}

.news-box {
  text-align: left;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding: 30px;
  flex-grow: 2;
}

.nav-bar {
  text-align: center;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

ul.link-list {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="top-container">

  <div class="top-content-box">

    <div class="nav-bar">
      <ul class="link-list">
        <li class="link-list"><a class="nav-list" href="default.asp">home</a></li>
        <li class="link-list"><a class="nav-list" href="news.asp">about</a></li>
        <li class="link-list"><a class="nav-list" href="contact.asp">projects</a></li>
        <li class="link-list"><a class="nav-list" href="about.asp">portfolio</a></li>
        <li class="link-list"><a class="nav-list" href="about.asp">commissions</a></li>
        <li class="link-list"><a class="nav-list" href="about.asp">patreon</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="news-and-twitter">
      <div class="news-box">
        <h1>current project</h1>
        Arena Circus ch 4 | Inserting voices into The Pretenders Guild
        <h1>Current Events</h1>
        <ul>
          <li>The Pretenders Guild voice update is coming 7/15/19!
          </li>
          <li>Check the 1 year anniversary <a href="https://www.patreon.com/posts/1-year-special-28267096">special offer</a> here!</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="twitter-min">
        <a class="twitter-timeline" data-width="300" data-height="450" data-theme="light" data-link-color="#343584" href="https://twitter.com/CapMinyan?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw">Tweets by CapMinyan</a>
        <script async src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js"
          charset="utf-8"></script>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H3rsW.jpg)

Comment: You can try using Flexbox. Learn about flexboxes here [ A Complete Guide to Flexbox ](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Comment: When I tried using flex, nothing happened. I'm not sure if I have to do something special before using it or what, but the boxes still just kind of sat there.

Answer (score 0):

Some may say *"use flex box"* but I really prefer not to do such methods!

So my suggestion would be position the nav bar `left:50%;`

And then give it a `margin-left: -100px` then change -100px to half of the nav's width, so lets say it has a width of 526px you put it to -263px.

And it may change it's width depending on the device's screen size, so I'd add some Javascript to change that when the page loads, so basically check what the width of the nav is then divide it by 2 and put a "-" in front of it then a "px" after it...

I understand if that sounds too complicated for such a simple task but I like using JavaScript to do my, ***things***

Also many would say this is dumb to do, because the less Javascript the better but I strongly disagree, but that's my opinion... Other than the fact that **a lot** of Javascript will make the page slower, and a few other things...

Alternatively try doing `margin: 0 auto` could fix the problem, worth a shot!

**Hope this helps!**

Answer (score 0):

You have to make the parent element of the list (ul.link-list) a flex and make the children (li.link-list) have flex-grow of 1

```
.top-container{

    text-align:center;


 }
 .top-content-box {
     width: 90%;
     height:30%;
     margin:30px auto;
     background: #fff;
     box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #000;  

 }

 .news-and-twitter{
   display:flex;
   flex-direction:row;
   flex-grow:1;
 }

 .twitter-min{

  width:300px;

 }

 .news-box{

  text-align:left;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding:30px;
  flex-grow:2;

 }
```